# Getting 503 Service with NodeJS/Httpd

Tags: node.js, apache, webserver

I am running my Node using `pm2 start` exact command is `pm2 start /apps/map/$name/server.js --node-args="--max_old_space_size=12096" --name server`.

I've been debugging heap space memory errors and was trying different values for `max_old_space`. I restarted the server with a new value and it never came up back online....

The problem is that I am not seeing any errors on my node console, and have restarted httpd which came up with no issues. My background is not in DevOps so I am lost as to what else I can look at.

I have tried:
1.) Kill Node repeatdly using `kill -9 pid`
2.) Running `netstap -lpn | grep 'node` to see if the server is listening/Up. Below is the output
3.) Restarting Node using the above command
4.) Restarting `httpd`

I am waiting on the logs from the sysadmin for httpd but I don't know what to try next...

```
netstat -lpn | grep 'node'
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19221/node /apps/ma
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8082          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19221/node /apps/ma[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, `server.js` was configured to listen to port 8081 on the App Server, and I incorrectly assumed it was configured exactly like my local machine which was listening to port 8080. Case solved.